# setting div height from body height

Tags: html, scroll, fullscreen

My body and html are height 100% and overflow hidden, but I need a div to be able to scroll its own contents.  Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pPGUB/1/) as you can see the content in the div scrolls up to a certain point.  I am trying to set it's height depending from the body height minus the header height and padding.

CSS:

```
body{ 
overflow:hidden;/* needed to eliminate scrollbars caused by the background image */
padding:0;
    margin:0;/* necesarry for the raster to fill the screen */
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
html{
   min-height:100%;
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
}
#header{
   height:70px;
   background:#000;
   color:#fff;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
#votes{
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
width:266px;
position:absolute;
right:0;
padding:5px 5px 50px;

color:#fff !important;
z-index: 99999;
  overflow:scroll;
```

}

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var height = $(document).height();
var divheight = height - 130;
$('#votes').attr('style', 'height:' + divheight + 'px');

});
```

Comment: Which background image is the comment referring to?

Answer (score 0):

overflow-y:auto; or overflow:scroll; keeps making the entire page scroll. You could always go for an iframe. its a horrible fix